# How to parse a json with dynamic property name in java?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I need to consume and parse incoming json from a CRM system in my code. I used RestTemplate to do it. So the response from the CRM system looks like below.

```
{ "GvyArEFkg6JX6wI": {
     "entityId": "GvyArEFkg6JX6wI",
     "mergePolicy": {
         "id": "9245a39d-fe1a-4b33-acab-9bc5cbabf37c"
     }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is the property name ("GvyArEFkg6JX6wI" in this case) in dynamic and in the next response it would be another string. In this case, how can I parse this json as this is not fixed? I tried using `jsonGetter` but it only wraps it around another block and still does not resolve the problem of parsing the response.

`AdobeResponseDto.class`

```
@Builder
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AdobeResponseDto {
    public Map<String, AdobeResponseFinal> adobeResponseWrapper = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdobeResponseWrapper(String name, AdobeResponseFinal value) {
        adobeResponseWrapper.put(name, value);
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, AdobeResponseFinal> getAdobeResponseWrapper() {
        return adobeResponseWrapper;
    }
}
```

`AdobeResponseFinal.class`

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AdobeResponseFinal {
    public String entityId;
    public MergePolicy mergePolicy;
}
```

I am calling the service like this:

```
final ResponseEntity<AdobeResponseDto> finalResponse;
finalResponse = aepClient.exchange(uri,HttpMethod.GET,entity,AdobeResponseDto.class);
final AdobeResponseDto body = finalResponse.getBody();

if(ObjectUtils.isNotEmpty(body)){
    return body;
}
```

But in this way, the response I am getting is

```
   {
    "adobeResponseWrapper": {
    "GvyArEFkg6JX6wI": {
        "entityId": "GvyArEFkg6JX6wI",
        "mergePolicy": {
            "id": "9245a39d-fe1a-4b33-acab-9bc5cbabf37c"
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to get the value of dynamic field name (e.g., "GvyArEFkg6JX6wI" in your case), you can just deserialize the response body to a `Map` and then traverse its value as follows:

```java
ResponseEntity<String> finalResponse = aepClient.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> result = objectMapper.readValue(finalResponse.getBody(), Map.class);
result.values().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Console output:

> {entityId=GvyArEFkg6JX6wI, mergePolicy={id=9245a39d-fe1a-4b33-acab-9bc5cbabf37c}}

---

And if you want to deserialize the response body to your DTO (I assume that there is only **ONE** root-level property), you can modify the DTO like:

```java
public class AdobeResponseDto {
    private AdobeResponseFinal adobeResponseFinal;

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdobeResponseFinal(String name, AdobeResponseFinal value) {
        adobeResponseFinal = value;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public AdobeResponseFinal getAdobeResponseFinal() {
        return adobeResponseFinal;
    }
}
```

Then you can get similar result as follows:

```java
ResponseEntity<String> finalResponse = aepClient.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
AdobeResponseDto adobeResponseDto = objectMapper.readValue(finalResponse.getBody(), AdobeResponseDto.class);
System.out.println(adobeResponseDto.getAdobeResponseFinal().toString());
```

Console output:

> AdobeResponseFinal{entityId='GvyArEFkg6JX6wI', mergePolicy=MergePolicy{id='9245a39d-fe1a-4b33-acab-9bc5cbabf37c'}}

Comment: Thank you, I followed the second approach but I am loosing the structure a little bit, I am getting exactly what you have written, so the dynamic property is missing in the response `{ "GvyArEFkg6JX6wI": {......}}` I wanted to keep the original response intact.

Comment: No problems! But I wonder know why you still want to keep the original response？