# Exclude indentifier of nested json but still take it's data - Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, mongodb

I have a post mapping method in my rest controller which takes a json and saves it in mongodb. I map this json in a class but I'm not able to retrieve it successfully after. The json has this format.

```
{
     "*random_generated_string*": {
                                    "field 1": value1,
                                    "field 2": value2,
                                    ...
                                   }
}
```

My understanding is that in order to map a json in to a class in spring I need to map every key of the json to a class property. I don't know how to map this random string. I decided it to exclude it but how? I want to still take it's contents and map them to my class.

P.S My class has these json fields as properties so it should be possible.

Comment: If you map your json into a java class and if your class does not have that field, it will ignore it.

Comment: It is not a very good design to have a random string as a key (field name). This can be refactored as `{ random_string: "some random value", other_details: { field1: "value 1", field2: 1234 } }`

Comment: @prasad_ I know that, but these data come from a different source, I don't have control over them.

Comment: You can still transform the data before storing it in the database.

Comment: @Andre But how do you ignore a random generated string as a key? And how do you take it's children? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @prasad_ I was hoping if there was a way to automate this before doing this. This was my last resort (to manipulate the json as such).

Comment: I think the only option is to map it to JsonObject or JsonArray and parse it manually.

Comment: Duplicate question? [How to parse a json with dynamic property name in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70702870/how-to-parse-a-json-with-dynamic-property-name-in-java/70704888#70704888)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was indeed to parse the object manually. Changed the controller to take a `Map<String, Object>` instead of the class object that I wanted to save and then manipulated the Object (value of the Map after casting it to a String). Then, using the setters I filled up the Object and saved it to the database.

**Code**

```
@PostMapping("/location")
  public void saveLocation(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> payload) {
    System.out.println(payload);

    for (Entry<String, Object> entry : payload.entrySet()) {
      System.out.println(entry.getValue());

      String[] props = String.valueOf(entry.getValue()).substring(1).split("}")[0].split(",");

      LocationM locationM = new LocationM();

      locationM.setAccuracy(Float.parseFloat(props[0].split("=")[1]));
      locationM.setAltitude(Float.parseFloat(props[1].trim().split("=")[1]));
      locationM.setCount(Integer.parseInt(props[2].trim().split("=")[1]));
      locationM.setLatitude(Float.parseFloat(props[3].trim().split("=")[1]));
      locationM.setLongitude(Float.parseFloat(props[4].trim().split("=")[1]));
      locationM.setSpeed(Integer.parseInt(props[5].trim().split("=")[1]));
      locationM.setTimestamp(Long.parseLong(props[6].trim().split("=")[1]));

      locationService.save(locationM);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Great! Can you share your code in your answer?

Comment: @Andre Just added it.